# Userform Listbox name click to populate textboxes from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and Stackoverflow but enjoy learning VBA and what it can do.
I've done some small code jobs and got a great kick start to get this far.

I have a Userform called Master Copy Ledger which has a Userform with a listbox (names of people pulled from worksheet), textboxes (have labels for the 12 months above the textboxes & labels to left side which has the stat I want to retrieve from a different workbook based on either name chosen from listbox or getdata command button which is beside the textbox)

the data I want to get is in the same workbook (for now) with names of people in column A and each stat in columns B, C, D through to column L.
I have a working copy now that when I choose a name I get the data for Sheet1 (Jan) but now need to figure out how to get Sheet2 (Feb), Sheet3 (Mar) and so on into the Userform and should it go in seperate textboxes or can I stretch the original textbox. If I have to use seperate textboxes then am I to assume I have to create new code for each 'getdata' function as I have done in the orignal or is there a loop function that checks all sheets and finds the name and gets the data and places into the textbox (stretched) or seperate textboxes.Eventually I will get to the point of learning to get from a different workbook but need to start somewhere and same workbook is where the code is working now so I say go with the flow till I have it down packed then I will look in the different workbook (20xxperformance.xlsx) which is 1 level up and once it finds that name it gathers the data from each column and places it in the correct textboxes.
Right now I have a working copy of the userform in 20xxperformance

```
Private Sub cbo_Agent_Change()
Dim Rws As Long, ConRng As Range, AdhRng As Range, AHTRng As Range, ACWRng As Range, TcktsRng As Range, LMIRng As Range, UnderRng As Range, KnowRng As Range, OvrSatRng As Range, OvrScoRng As Range, NPSRng As Range, Agnt As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
    Set Agnt = Rng.Find(what:=cbo_Agent, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set ConRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 1)   'set ConRng
    Set AdhRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 2)  'set AdhRng
    Set AHTRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 3)  'set AHTRng
    Set ACWRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 4)  'set AHTRng
    Set TcktsRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 5)  'set TcktsRng
    Set LMIRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 6)  'set LMIRng
    Set UnderRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 7)  'set UnderRng
    Set KnowRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 8)  'set KnowRng
    Set OvrSatRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 9)  'set OvrSatRng
    Set OvrScoRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 10)  'set OvrScoRng
    Set NPSRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 11)  'set NPSRng
    txt_Con = ConRng
    txt_Adh = AdhRng
    txt_AHT = AHTRng
    txt_ACW = ACWRng
    txt_tckts = TcktsRng
    txt_LMI = LMIRng
    txt_Under = UnderRng
    txt_Know = KnowRng
    txt_Osat = OvrSatRng
    txt_OScor = OvrScoRng
    txt_NPS = NPSRng
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
    cbo_Agent.List = Rng.Value

End Sub
```

As I mentioned i am new to VBA, feel I have accomplished more with everyone's help and find myself looking for expert advise again and need some help. I am not looking for the whole code (humbly accept if someone did though)for it all but at least another kick of great code so i can understand and put to practice your teachings.

thank you

ptpapa

[image]

Comment: http://www.xlorate.com/userform-vba-page.html or https://youtu.be/YRdpw7mn9-g or https://youtu.be/Hj1yzawOiog to get you started. Once you know how to populate a userform control, then you can start working on populating controls from a different workbook

Comment: Deleted my comments, updated the post and included the code.

Comment: So what happened with this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this sample will help you, if you use named ranges instead of normal range A1:A10 will reduce time and code lines as well :)

```
Public Sub comboval()
Dim spath As String
spath = "file path"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=spath
    With ActiveWorkbook

        Combobox1.List = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("namedranmge1").Value
        Combobox2.List = .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("namedranmge2").Value

        .Close 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Named range in detail [Click Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html)

Comment: Could you not loop through the sheets?

Comment: thank you Davesexcel, I will definitely give this a go and will let you know how it turns out but where would I put the code? would it go under the private sub cbo_agent change()? or the initialize one?

Comment: It should go in form initialize :)

Answer (score 0):

You could name each textbox in the Month column for example Jan1,Jan2,Feb1,Feb2 ect.

The when you loop through the sheets you can add to the textboxes by there name
`Controls(sh.Name & x).Value = .Cells(r, 1 + x)`
 The full code would look like this, I just used a small example when I wrote the code, so I only have used three textboxes per month

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range, r


    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh
            rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rws, 1))
            Set c = rng.Find(what:=ComboBox1, lookat:=xlWhole)
            r = c.Row
            For x = 1 To 3
                Controls(sh.Name & x).Value = .Cells(r, 1 + x)
            Next x
        End With
    Next sh

End Sub
```

[image: Sheet][image: Result]

You can download the sample workbook here, see how the textboxes are named.

[UserForm Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXxMRXssekcWlBCWGE5bVhtYnc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you Davesexcel; I have used something very similar too this and am posting the results that got what I needed thanks to you. You have been a good mentor and I feel I can look to you for good advise. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I managed to put together with Davesexcel's advise and examples:

```
Private Sub cbo_Agent_Change(Target_Workbook As Workbook)
Dim Rws As Long, ConRng As Range, AdhRng As Range, AHTRng As Range, ACWRng As Range, TcktsRng As Range, LMIRng As Range, UnderRng As Range, KnowRng As Range, OvrSatRng As Range, OvrScoRng As Range, NPSRng As Range, Agnt As Range
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim control_item
Dim Rng
Dim total_counter(11) As Single
Dim total_items As Integer

Dim Rng0
For intCounter = 1 To 12 'Goes through each individual month looking for stats

    Rws = Target_Workbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Rws > 1 Then 'This confirms there are stats for this month
        With Target_Workbook.Worksheets(intCounter)

            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
            Set Agnt = Rng.Find(what:=lstNames, lookat:=xlWhole) 'Search for the employee in pull down menu

        End With

        Set ConRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 1)   'set ConRng
        Set AdhRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 2)  'set AdhRng
        Set AHTRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 3)  'set AHTRng
        Set ACWRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 4)  'set AHTRng
        Set TcktsRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 5)  'set TcktsRng
        Set LMIRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 6)  'set LMIRng
        Set UnderRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 7)  'set UnderRng
        Set KnowRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 8)  'set KnowRng
        Set OvrSatRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 9)  'set OvrSatRng
        Set OvrScoRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 10)  'set OvrScoRng
        Set NPSRng = Agnt.Offset(0, 11)  'set NPSRng

        'This fills the table with data
        With MonthlyStats 'These save all the information to the necessary text fields
            .Controls("txt_Con" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(ConRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_Adh" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(AdhRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_AHT" & intCounter) = AHTRng
            .Controls("txt_ACW" & intCounter) = ACWRng
            .Controls("txt_tckts" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(TcktsRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_LMI" & intCounter) = LMIRng
            .Controls("txt_Under" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(UnderRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_Know" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(KnowRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_Osat" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(OvrSatRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_OScor" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(OvrScoRng, "0.0%")
            .Controls("txt_NPS" & intCounter) = VBA.Format(NPSRng, "0.0%")
        End With

        'This keeps track of all the values for each row to later be used to figure out the average
        total_counter(0) = total_counter(0) + ConRng
        total_counter(1) = total_counter(1) + AdhRng
        total_counter(2) = total_counter(2) + AHTRng
        total_counter(3) = total_counter(3) + ACWRng
        total_counter(4) = total_counter(4) + TcktsRng
        total_counter(5) = total_counter(5) + LMIRng
        total_counter(6) = total_counter(6) + UnderRng
        total_counter(7) = total_counter(7) + KnowRng
        total_counter(8) = total_counter(8) + OvrSatRng
        total_counter(9) = total_counter(9) + OvrScoRng
        total_counter(10) = total_counter(10) + NPSRng

        total_items = total_items + 1
    End If

Next

'This will figure out the average of each line
txt_ConfYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(0) / total_items, "0.0%")
txt_AdhYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(1) / total_items, "0.0%")
txt_AHTYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(2) / total_items, "0.00")
txt_ACWYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(3) / total_items, "0.00")
txt_tcktsYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(4) / total_items, "0.0%")
txt_LMIYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(5) / total_items, "0.00")
txt_UnderYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(6) / total_items, "0.0%")
txt_KnowYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(7) / intCounter, "0.0%")
txt_OsatYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(8) / intCounter, "0.0%")
txt_OScorYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(9) / intCounter, "0.0%")
txt_NPSYTD = VBA.Format(total_counter(10) / intCounter, "0.0%")


End Sub
```